# What MIME type should I send with a legacy DOS image type that must be saved and not displayed?

Tags: http, http-headers, mime-types, basic

I need to allow my users to download BSAVE "images" from my webserver. BASVE "image" files are a raw dump of a segment of RAM which contains screen data mostly used in BASIC programming. No browser can display this image, rather it is "displayed" by BLOADing it back into RAM.

I don't believe application/octet-stream is correct because it isn't an executable but sending any image/* MIME type would be inaccurate and confusing. Sending the file as text would be inaccurate and confusing as well.

Which MIME type will allow the download/save of the file while being the most accurate descriptor of the file and its contents? Is application/octet-stream the most possibly correct wrong answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application/octet-stream` can be (and usually is) used for any raw data, it is not just for executables (which would normally be `application/x-msdos-program`, `application/x-msdownload`, `application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable`, etc instead).  Its name literally says it is a "stream of octets" (aka bytes).  The `application/...` portion of the name does not refer to *executable applications*, it actually means that the data is meant to be typically *consumed by* applications.

You should also include a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="..."` response header to indicate to the client that the data should be saved to a file instead of displayed in the browser.

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.bsave"
```